# six-digit number divisible by 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If abcdef is a six-digit number and if 8 divides the three-digit number def, then 8 divides abcdef.

I feel like I am missing something huge. Cannot figure this out. I have tried it with many cases and I understand that it works. I am looking for a way to prove this directly.

Comment: Hint: 8 divides 1000.

Comment: You could write the number in two parts: abc000+def. Since abc000 ends in 000 it is divisible by 8 (as hinted by @Alvin), also, def is divisible by 8, so the entire number must be divisible by 8.

Answer (score 3):

The number written $abcdef$ is numerically

$$\begin{align*}
100000a+10000b+1000c+100d+10e+f&=1000(100a+10b+c)+(100d+10e+f)\\
&=8\cdot125(100a+10b+c)+(100d+10e+f)\;.
\end{align*}$$

If $100d+10e+f$, the number written $def$, is a multiple of $8$, then $100d+10e+f=8n$ for some integer $n$, and our $abcdef$ is equal to

$$\begin{align*}
8\cdot125(100a+10b+c)+(100d+10e+f)&=8\cdot125(100a+10b+c)+8n\\
&=8\big(125(100a+10b+c)+n\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

a multiple of $8$.

As an exercise, try showing that a number written in the usual base ten notation is divisible by $4$ if and only if the two-digit number formed by its last two digits is divisible by $4$; the argument uses the same basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer $1000a+b,$ where $0\le b\le999$

$(1000a+b)-b\equiv0\pmod8$

$\implies8\mid(1000a+b)\iff8\mid b$